# SQL - Select all rows from one table that have a similar value with a different prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have a table with around 1million rows.
In the fileID column there has been some accidental duplication.
This column can have 7 or 8 digit numbers stored as a string.

I need to search for all 7-digit values that have a corresponding entry that is the same seven digits with a '0' (zero) prefixing it.

So, while there should only be a row with value '1234567' in fileID, there is now a new row with '01234567' that has been entered in error. I believe around 10,000 rows have been affected, and the incorrect entries need to be removed.

How would I write a SQL query to select only rows that have a corresponding 0-prefixed row, and return both rows in the results?

CLARIFICATION EDIT:
Some valid data has already been entered into the records with incorrect fileID, so the output I need would ideally have a row with a 7-digit fileID followed by any corresponding rows that have an eight digit fileID with leading '0'.

fileID   other1 other2
1234567  xxxxxx xxxxxxx
01234567 xxxxxx xxxxxxx
1234566  xxxxxx xxxxxxx
01234566 xxxxxx xxxxxxx

Comment: Do you have a query that you have started that we could use for reference? Also, can you include the table structure in the question?

Comment: Why can't you use the `like '0%'` statement?

Comment: Is `0` an invalid value as the first character or is it allowed?

Comment: @Ronan Muldoon I've updated my answer to show the output in the required format

Answer (score 3):

You could group outputs by the last 7 characters like so:

```
SELECT RIGHT(fileID ,7) AS FileId, count(*) RecordCount
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
GROUP BY RIGHT(fileID ,7)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will highlight duplicate records based on the last 7 characters. You could use this result in a temp table and then filter that to highlight the rows that start with `0`.

So first insert in to a temp table:

```
SELECT RIGHT(fileID ,7) AS FileId, count(*) RecordCount
INTO #temp  
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
GROUP BY RIGHT(fileID ,7)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then output those starting with `0` with 8 characters:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #temp 
WHERE LEFT (FileId,1) = '0' and LEN(FileId) = 8
```

Comment: Don't you mean to GROUP BY RIGHT(fileid,1)? Also can you SELECT fileid?

Comment: @DavidG Yep, deleted it by mistake whilst modifying my source query

Comment: But I don't think you can SELECT FileId as it's not in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Works on my machine... FileID is an alias for the RIGHT(...)

Comment: Though I'd be tempted to add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to only show the duplicates.

Comment: the risk with this one is that if there are a 91234567 and a 81234567 it will report them as duplicates

Comment: @RonanMuldoon no problem, I see this is your first post, it might be useful to read this, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/251594 which advises you what to do when your question has been answered.

Comment: It is my first post, yes! Appreciate the update - I actually hit enter before I added the rest: Thanks for the help, guys. This seems close to what I need. The issue is that your second SELECT query will return nothing as you have already trimmed the data in the #temp database to 7 characters. To clarify, the data in the 'leading 0' records would need to be reviewed and compared to the data in the 7-digit records before deleting, as some additional information has since been added to other columns on the incorrect records. This will have to be updated into the correct columns before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description in your question, I think the `like '0%'` statement will just do fine. However, like you said, you may delete way too many records, so my other suggestion is to check for the length.

Since you mentioned the fileID should be only 7 digit, so you can check for condition if the length is more than 7 digit:

```
Select fileID from SomeTable where fileID like '0%' and len(fileID) > 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This should produce the required output:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(fileID AS NUMERIC(18,0))
IN(
SELECT cast(fileID AS NUMERIC(18,0)) FROM table 
group BY CAST(fileID AS NUMERIC(18,0)) HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Comment: This will error if any rows contain non-numeric values.

Comment: yes, it's only valid if the ids are numbers, but the questions explicitly says they are numbers stored as string

Comment: @Jayvee I've tried this, but some of the fileid values are up to 16 digits, which is causing an overflow in an int column: "The conversion of the varchar value '61574481815568' overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded." (I'd not mentioned that they could be longer as it was only the seven and eight digit values that I was concerned with. Sorry!)

Comment: @Ronan Muldoon , you can then cast as NUMERIC(18,0) or bigint and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

**UNTESTED**

```
SELECT distinct T1.* FROM TABLE AS T1 
   RIGHT JOIN TABLE T2 
      ON T1.fileID like '%0'+T2.fileID
```

Comment: It's good practice to add an explanation for why your answer is a good solution, rather than just just dropping code.

Comment: sorry :$ (btw i updated the query) all i dide is joind the tablt to it self to get all the lines that have a duplicate with prefix '0' in the fileID i used distinct so i dont get the same line twice